# Changing what DataTemplate is used by a GridView programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-rt

I am creating a Windows RT app that uses a main `GridView` to list videos.  The videos are shown as thumbnails and clicking on the thumbnail takes you to another page that shows the video.

My question is, how can I switch out what template is used for the `GridView`?

I have a "Small Icons" template right now that shows 12 video thumbnails on the screen at once, but I'm developing another view that shows 2 really big thumbnails at once.  I want to be able to have the user click a button and switch between the views.  The data on the backend will be the same, only the view changes.  My best example is in windows explorer, how you can change between Large Icons, Small Icons, Details etc.  I'm doing this in C# on Windows RT.

Comment: It is often easier to help if you include some code and show what you have already tried.

Comment: Sounds like datatemplateselector

Comment: I guess I misunderstood how DataTemplateSelector worked, I was under the assumption it was on an item-by-item basis, not for the whole template.  I'm going to look into it and I'll mark an answer when I get an answer, thank you.

Comment: I got it working, thank you for answering my question!

Comment: I don't know how to mark your answer correct though.  I'm new to the site as a poster, been following for a long time as a reader.